# I take great pride or I take a great pride

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns

Which one sounds better grammatically?

- I take a great pride in my family.
- I take great pride in my family.

I know that *pride* sometimes can be a count/noncount noun. But I am not sure about the case above.

Comment: Hi @skybluemint, welcome to **English Language & Usage**. Ideally, questions on ELU should reflect _some_ degree of research having taken place. If applicable, please cite any source(s) you've explored regarding this question. _Thanks!_

Comment: I would be more inclined to use the article if I'm talking about something specific, such as "I take a great pride in my father-in-law's firm stance against corruption."  But note that you can't go wrong with omitting the article, in any situation.

Answer (score 3):

While both of these version can be found in print:

1. I take great pride in my family.
2. I take ***a*** great pride in my family.

The first version — the one without the article — is on the order of [around a hundred times more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+great+pride+in%2C+take+a+great+pride+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20great%20pride%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20great%20pride%20in%3B%2Cc0) than the second:

[image: google ngram of the two possibilities]

Since both occur in the writings of native speakers, both are by definition grammatical. It’s up to you how you say it. I recommend checking [the citations that use *take a great pride in*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22take%20a%20great%20pride%20in%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) to see how those sound to you.

I’m not sure it’s reasonable to say that placing the indefinite article and an adjective before a noncount noun converts it into a count noun. After all, uou still haven’t made a plural out of it.  The only sense of *pride* where it is clearly a count noun is when you’re talking about various *prides of lions* found across the African savannah.

However, it is nonetheless possible in certain circumstances to place *a/an* before nouns that do not typically take an indefinite article. In particular, because you are here using the adjective *great* to limit *pride*, you’re limiting it from the most general, abstract sense which that word typically carries.

Consider the difference between having cake at Christmas and having a Christmas to remember. It’s a way of delineating a concrete instance of that noun. However, *Christmas* and *Easter* can be turned into count nouns far more readily than *pride* can, lions excepted.

There are several questions related to yours over on our sister site for English Language Learners where this is explored in greater detail:

- [Does an uncountable noun take an article if it has an adjective before it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/16694/141)
- [Using indefinite articles before adjectives: “Let's have a good breakfast”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/80429/141)

There are others besides.